# If $D$ is a ultrafilter on $I$ and $(a_i) \mapsto_{D} a$ and $f_i \mapsto_{D} f$ then $ Sup_{x}f_i(x, a_i) \mapsto_{D} Sup_{x} f(x, a)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $(x_i)_i \in I$ be a family of elements of $X$. If $D$ is an ultrafilter on $I$ and $x \in X$, we write
$$x_i \mapsto_{D} x$$
if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, the set $\{ i \in I : x_i \in U \}$ is in the ultrafilter $D$.

I want to show that if $(a_i) \mapsto_{D} a$ and $f_i \mapsto_{D} f$ then $ Sup_{x}f_i(x, a_i) \mapsto_{D} Sup_{x} f(x, a)$, where $f_i : \mathbb{R}^2  \rightarrow [0,1]$ is continuous.

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true?  It fails even for convergent sequences, you know.

Comment: Which convergent sequence is fail? I know that $sup_x(lim_{i,D} F_i(x)) \le lim_{i,D} (sup_x F_i(x))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example.  It seems $X = \mathbb R$ in your statement...

Let $I = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$.  Define
$$
a_i = \frac{1}{i},\qquad a=0 .
$$
So of course $a_i \to a$.

Define $f_i$ by: $f_i(x,a_i) = 1$, $f_i(x,y) = 0$ for $y \le a_{i+1}$ or $y \ge a_{i-1}$ and interpolate linearly on each side of $a_i$.  Then for each $i$, we have $f_i(x,y)$ is independent of $x$ and continuous in $y$, therefore jointly continuous.
Define $f(x,y) = 0$, also jointly continuous.  But
$$
f_i(x,y) \to 0,\qquad\text{for all } x,y,
$$
so $f_i \to f$.  [Of course this convergence is not uniform, but the problem did not require that.]

Next,
$$
\lim_i \sup_x f_i(x,a_i) = 1 \ne 0 = \lim_i \sup_x f_i(x,a)
$$
but this is just because
$$
f_i(x,a_i) = 1 \text{ for all } x,i,
\\
f_i(x,a) = 0 \text{ for all } x,i .
$$

Comment: Thank you! How about $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniform? Do you think this's true?